# Need to open SQL Server Management Studio 2008 from "Run" menu

Tags: windows, ssms

I tried to open SQL Server Management Studio 2008 by typing `ssms` in "Run" menu.

But it wont open.

It shows

> *windows cannot find 'ssms'. make sure you typed the name correctly, and try again".*

But it works from start-> program->sql server 2008.

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to open SQL Server **Management Studio** from `Run`. SQL Server itself is a *service*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either:

A) need to go to the path where SQL Server 2008/SSMS is installed (i.e. C:\Program Files\SQL Server 2008...)

***OR***

B) you have to add the path to ssms.exe to your `PATH` environmental variable, and then you can just type SSMS in the Run window. Here is a [LINK](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) where you can find more details about this.

Comment: In Environmental Variables under SYSTEM VARIABLES, the Path is like this  %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem and i add C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server by seperating with semicolon(;) then also i am unable to open ssms from run window

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer worked, please don't forget to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: One other very common issue is that when u install a new version of SQL Server then typing `SSMS` command on run prompt will continue to open the SSMS application of older SQL Server version. Like when I installed SQL Server 2014 (with SQL Server 2012 already installed), typing `SSMS` on run prompt continues to open SSMS application associated with SQL Server 2012 only. To fix this issue, again this `PATH` environment variable will come into picture. Just move the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;` to the starting of `PATH` variable and save it.